Arc: how to enable audio player for my own website?
I'm trying to enable the Arc browser audio player on a webpage of mine.
I cannot find any documentation from Arc targeted to developers though, so I tried by using what works for Google Chrome, but it doesn't seem to work.
So far, here's what I have, in an Angular context:
podcast.component.html
  <audio controls="controls" (playing)="onPlay()">
    <source src="assets/audio/ComplexPortal%20-%20Overview%20podcast.mp3">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 Audio element.
  </audio>

podcast.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'cp-podcast',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './podcast.component.html',
  styleUrl: './podcast.component.scss'
})
export class PodcastComponent {
  onPlay(): void {
    navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
      title: 'Complex Portal - Overview Podcast',
      artist: 'Complex Portal',
      album: 'Complex Portal - Podcast',
      artwork: [{src: 'assets/images/CP-square-profile.png'}],
    });
  }
}

Also my audio file does contain the meta-data about title, artists, cover, etc. and yet nothing gets displayed by Arc when switching to another tab, as it does for Youtube Music or Spotify.
I created this StackBlitz to showcase what I currently have: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-pxppkj?file=src%2Fmain.ts
How to make it work?

I noticed right after publishing that ithe Audio player started to work on Arc with my example, so I guess the answer I have is already working. It might just have required a restart of Arc browser, unsure why now it works and not initially, but he, problem solved!

The code that I submitted actually works, so here's the solution https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-pxppkj?file=src%2Fmain.ts
